# why doesn't my function launch after calling it in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to launch a script when I click on an html button with django, I get what's have been entered in the input when I click on the button but the rest of the script in my function doesn't run although when tried alone in a py file it works normally

So I got here

index.html :

```html
<form action='/' method="get">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="text" class="input" name="result" placeholder="Search...">

                <button class="btn" type="submit">
                    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                </button>
```

views.py

```py
def play(request):
  inp_value = request.GET.get('result', '')
  context = {'inp_value': inp_value}
  print(context)
  chpath = 'C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'    
  webbrowser.get(chpath).open('google.com')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('/', views.play, name="play")
]
```

So when I click on the button search, only the url change as for example :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=xYQaShcfX3apwjaOTeYvNsiXV4qXZoG3W4K5yP582IKAljAE1o0clnCagpVW3MPT&result=hey
```

If someone could give me a hand I would be really grateful I am not able to find why

Thanks

Comment: I agree with @francisco. You dont need a csrf token in a get request. The fact that those params appear in the url bar actually means that part of your script is working. The line that's supposed to launch a web browser is failing. I'd focus on that.

Comment: Okay thank you ! I am correcting this then

Comment: The problem is that you are using the {% csrf token %} in a get request when you just need use this tag in a post request.